# Calculating movement values from an array of balance values

Tags: mongodb

**Does anyone know how to calculate the difference of values between documents? So, on current document value deduct the previous document value to create a new value of the movement. Each document represents a month and year balance.**

I have a set of account_balances in a document which are dated at the end of each month. They represent the general ledger from accounting app where the integration only provides the balances and not the month by month movement.

How would I calculate the difference of a balance value from an array  of one document and the previous month's document?

The parameters to group together correctly are the _id.company, _id.connection, _id.object_snapshot_date and then account_balances.account_id and account_balances.value_type.

The value I want to deduct total_value of each account from 2018-05-30 from total_value from the 2018-06-31 document. There may be multiple documents in here related to an entire year.

What I want to get is the same document back but the total_value for June is the movement instead of the balance.

Thanks, Matt

Example of two documents with different months:

```
{
"_id" : {
  "company" : " a8aa7d3f-cef8-4895-a83e-3087b4cf529c ",
  "connection" : "a4b52d3a-0c00-406f-9163-4b1d52df0271",
  "object_snapshot_date" : 20180603135959,
  "object_schema" : "timeline-balance",
  "object_class" : "trial-balance",
  "object_category" : "balance",
  "object_type" : "month",
  "object_origin_category" : "bookkeeping",
  "object_origin_type" : "accounting",
  "object_origin" : "Xero"
 },
"account_balances" : [
{
  "account_id" : "47cf9c6e-4ec7-4853-9efa-9e180636c96f",
  "account_name" : "Sales",
  "account_code" : "200",
  "account_class" : "revenue",
  "account_category" : "sales",
  "account_group" : "",
  "value_type" : "credit",
  "total_value" : 29928.96,
  "value_currency" : "NZD"
},
{
  "account_id" : "47cf9c6e-4ec7-4853-9efa-9e180636aa43",
  "account_name" : "Cost of Goods Sold",
  "account_code" : "300",
  "account_class" : "expense",
  "account_category" : "sales",
  "account_group" : "",
  "value_type" : "debit",
  "total_value" : 12452.50,
  "value_currency" : "NZD"
}
]
},
{
"_id" : {
  "company" : " a8aa7d3f-cef8-4895-a83e-3087b4cf529c ",
  "connection" : "a4b52d3a-0c00-406f-9163-4b1d52df0271",
  "object_snapshot_date" : 20180503035959,
  "object_schema" : "timeline-balance",
  "object_class" : "trial-balance",
  "object_category" : "balance",
  "object_type" : "month",
  "object_origin_category" : "bookkeeping",
  "object_origin_type" : "accounting",
  "object_origin" : "Xero"
 },
"account_balances" : [
{
  "account_id" : "47cf9c6e-4ec7-4853-9efa-9e180636c96f",
  "account_name" : "Sales",
  "account_code" : "200",
  "account_class" : "revenue",
  "account_category" : "sales",
  "account_group" : "",
  "value_type" : "credit",
  "total_value" : 24231.12,
  "value_currency" : "NZD"
},
{
  "account_id" : "47cf9c6e-4ec7-4853-9efa-9e180636aa43",
  "account_name" : "Cost of Goods Sold",
  "account_code" : "300",
  "account_class" : "expense",
  "account_category" : "sales",
  "account_group" : "",
  "value_type" : "debit",
  "total_value" : 6875.10,
  "value_currency" : "NZD"
}
]
}
```

Expected Output would be like this:

```
{
"_id" : {
  "company" : " a8aa7d3f-cef8-4895-a83e-3087b4cf529c ",
  "connection" : "a4b52d3a-0c00-406f-9163-4b1d52df0271",
  "object_snapshot_date" : 20180603135959,
  "object_schema" : "timeline-balance",
  "object_type" : "month",
  "object_origin_category" : "bookkeeping",
  "object_origin" : "Xero"
},
"account_movements" : [
 {
  "account_id" : "47cf9c6e-4ec7-4853-9efa-9e180636c96f",
  "account_name" : "Sales",
  "account_code" : "200",
  "account_class" : "revenue",
  "movement" : 5697.84
 },
 {
  "account_id" : "47cf9c6e-4ec7-4853-9efa-9e180636aa43",
  "account_name" : "Cost of Goods Sales",
  "account_code" : "200",
  "account_class" : "revenue",
  "movement" : 5577.4
 }
]
}
```

Comment: the total value of sales movement should be 5697.84

Comment: and total value of cost of sales should be 5577.40

Comment: any ideas? I have been through the forums and with exception to a couple of similar posts which I had no hope of understanding or relating to my problem, nothing. Help please, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you can always put a filtering condition that will guarantee that only two documents remain after [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) stage (like below). Then you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single `account_balance` per document. In the next stage you can [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) by `snapshot_date`. Then you can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `account_name` with [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/index.html) to get all `balances`. Since there is an assumption that there will be only two elements you can use [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/index.html) with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get the movement.

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "_id.object_snapshot_date": {
                $gte: 20180500000000, 
                $lte: 20180630000000
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$account_balances"
    },
    {
        $sort: { "_id.object_snapshot_date": 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$account_balances.account_name",
            balances: { $push: "$account_balances.total_value" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            account_name: "$_id",
            movement: { $subtract: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$balances", 1 ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$balances", 0 ] } ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Outputs:

```
{ "account_name" : "Cost of Goods Sold", "movement" : 5577.4 }
{ "account_name" : "Sales", "movement" : 5697.84 }
```

If you need more generic solution (for more than two months) you can replace last pipeline stage with below:

```
{
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            account_name: "$_id",
            movement: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ 1, { $size: "$balances" } ] },
                    as: "index",
                    in: {
                        $subtract: [
                            { $arrayElemAt: [ "$balances", "$$index" ] },
                            { $arrayElemAt: [ "$balances", { $subtract: [ "$$index", 1 ] } ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will calculate the differences for all the values in `balances` array using (you'll get `n-1` results where `n` is a size of `balances`).

Comment: thanks for this, I'll try that out tomorrow. There is likely to be 12 months worth, each with a value of movement between the months. Awesome to see something that might just work :)

Comment: Wow, yes! That works a beaut! I haven't tried on multiple docs but have used the second $project pipeline. I take it that the context of those records is from the latest doc not the previous one - so, if I also project the _id.object_snapshot_date it will be that of the newest document with the movement calculated from that to the previous one? I hope that makes sense

Comment: additional to the date, I also need the company, connection and object_origin from the document _ids as I will have multiple companies in here. Thanks

Comment: @MattLightbourn not sure if I understand, could you paste expected result ?

Comment: I've amended the original question to include expected output. Thanks

Comment: @MattLightbourn it complicates a bit, but still feasible, I will try to find a moment tomorrow morning to update my answer

Comment: thank you @mickl - It doesn't all need to be in an array in a single document, but the details of the values (company, connection, account_id and account_name) would be really great. I have modified your script to $group by the account_id instead of name because the name is editable and may create issues whereas the account_id won't change.

Comment: @MattLightbourn I think that it would to be complicated from code perspective. As a fallback you can add `details: { $first: "$$ROOT" }` to `$group` stage and then `details: 1` in `$project` and it will be a way easier to merge it then in your application logic

Comment: I'll give that a go, that looks like it could work very well thanks :)

Comment: the only stuff I really need in there are from the _id values so, would that make it details: {$first: "$_id" } and then I could select the values I want to project from $details.x ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that should give you all the details

Comment: that works awesomely! Just one final thing, the movement figure is in an array. Is it possible for it to be movement : 5671.67 instead of movement : [ 5671.67]? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can add `{ $unwind: "$movement" }` after `$project` if you're sure that there will be only one value